# How to display cakes name from file?

Tags: c++

```
int Cake(const char* nazwaPliku)
{
    ifstream we;
    we.open(nazwaPliku);

    if( !we.good() )
    {
        cerr << "Problem with file read"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    char a;
    getline((a))
    {
        cout<<a;
    }

    we.close();
}
```

I have a problem with getline. I want to display cakes name from file.txt. The file.txt look like:

```
cheesecake;2;5;
chocoladecake;5;7;
applecake;5;6;
```

Comment: Looks like you need  a while loop instead of  `getline((a))`

Comment: This show me error: no matching function for call to getline(char&)

Comment: It should give you that error. You are missing a parameter ( the stream). `while (getline(we, a))  { // do something with a }`

Comment: Could you show me in which place missing a parameter ?

Comment: Now show me error: no matching function for call to getline(std::ifstream&, char&)

Comment: `char a;` should be `std::string a;` and you probably want to name your variables better. Never use a single letter name for a variable that is not  a loop index.

Comment: Ok, It's work, but show me everything with file, but I want to only display cakes name without numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole line and split it or you can read the elements of the line:

```
std::string name;
char semicolon;
int number;
while (we >> name >> semicolon >> number >> semicolon >> number >> semicolon) {
    std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```